# Problem with left join with contition typeorm

Tags: node.js, database, typeorm

This is my code:

```
 const query = this.requestRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('request')
      .leftJoinAndMapMany(
        'request.approvers',
        RequestApprover,
        'approvers',
        'request.id = approvers.requestId',
      );
```

And this is data I got from query:

```
"requests": 
[
    {
        "id": "8ceee413-521c-4e21-a75b-27048d184804",
        "status": "waiting",
        "reason": "1",
         "approvers": [
             {
                 "id": "04946109-ba35-4c08-a469-761023f33b3c",
                 "employeeCode": "EMP001",
                 "status": "waiting",
            },
            {
                "id": "a9dec055-e237-434c-897e-d877f64df4af",
                "employeeCode": "EMP002",
                "status": "approved",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The problem is that when I add contidion to get all request which have been approve by employee EMP002

```
query.andWhere(`approvers.employeeCode = 'EMP002'`)
```

The approvers[0] is missing. I know that's correct but I wonder if there is a way to get full approvers but still get requests which have EMP002 is a approver. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two queries. First, get all the `id`s of the request where `approvers.employeeCode = 'EMP002'`. Then get all the `request`s where `id` of `request` equals the `requestId`s fetched above.

```
const results = await this.requestRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('request')
    .leftJoinAndMapMany(
        'request.approvers',
        RequestApprover,
        'approvers',
        'request.id = approvers.requestId',
    )
    .select('request.id', 'id')
    .where('approvers.employeeCode = :empCode', { empCode: 'EMP002' })
    .getRawMany();
const requestIds = results.map(e => e.id);
const requests = await this.requestRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('request')
    .leftJoinAndMapMany(
        'request.approvers',
        RequestApprover,
        'approvers',
        'request.id = approvers.requestId',
    )
    .where('request.id IN (:...requestIds)', { requestIds: requestIds });
```

`requests` would now contain the desired result.